# Из блока catch снова вернуться в catch

Tags: java

Всем привет. Интересует вопрос, можно ли из блока `catch` снова вернуться в этот блок `catch`? Вот код:

```
try {
   model = mNetworkDataManager.getModel(mUserScore.get(qNum));
} catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e(TAG, "Данные не дошли. Сообщение: " + e.getMessage());

   model = mNetworkDataManager.getModel(mUserScore.get(qNum));
}
```

суть в том, что если данные не дошли (бывает), мне нужно повторить запрос. Но компилятор требует, чтобы я строку `model = ...` в блоке `catch` опять поместил в конструкцию `try - catch`. Мне нужно добиться того, чтобы `model != null`. Как это можно сделать? Данные, кстати, загружаю через `retrofit2`

Comment: Подсказка: рекурсия :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja рекурсии, конечно, хотелось бы избежать, оперативная память не бесконечна)

Comment: Все верно, кол-во попыток надо разумно ограничить в любом случае. Без рекурсии можно в цикле, но он тоже не может быть бесконечным.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja т.е, чтобы это было красиво, сделать нельзя? Попробую тогда рекурсией, посмотрю, что из этого выйдет. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так в цикле, возможно, будет лучше читаемо чем рекурсия.

```
Model model = null;
int attempts = 3;
do {
    try {
       model = mNetworkDataManager.getModel(mUserScore.get(qNum));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Данные не дошли. Сообщение: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    attempts--;
} while (attempts > 0 && model == null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0;
int tries = 3;

while(true) {//Пример цикла, копировать с умом
    try {
        // КОД
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Описание ошибки
        if (++count == tries) throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(true)` не надо так

Comment: это пример и все

Comment: начинающий разработчик скопирует это к себе в код и все

Comment: дописал чтоб копировали с умом, ведь коменты к коду же все читают

Comment: Держите плюс =)